# in this java script animation second time animating is not work correctly

Tags: javascript, css

http://jsfiddle.net/WPjvF/

when i click start button 1st time its work correctly, but after clicking reverse button, then i click again start button "ahh6" is appearing first. how to correct it.

```
var doWork = (function () {
"use strict";

var index = 0,
    boxes = $(".box1, .box2, .box3, .box4, .box5, .box6"),
    cur;

$("#home").click(function () {
    cur = 1;
    doWork(function (el) {
        el.addClass("animated");
    });
});

$("#home2").click(function () {
    cur = -1;
    doWork(function (el) {
        el.removeClass("animated");
    }, true);
});

return function (changer, reverse) {
    var start = function () {
        if ((reverse && index < 0) || (!reverse && index === boxes.length)) {
            return;
        }
        changer(boxes.eq(index));
        index += cur;
        setTimeout(start, 300);
    };
    start();
};
```

}());

Comment: its working alright,but just asking...yes a6 ppears first...but its still fine as it eventually comes to the bottom.

Comment: but i need to work animation perfectly, in exact order. can you correct this matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/WPjvF/1/

You're reverse function leaves index at -1.

```
$("#home").click(function () {
    if ( index < 0 ) index = 0;
    cur = 1;
    doWork(function (el) {
        el.addClass("animated");
    });
});
```